# Is this Mysql conditional join possible?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have done a bit of searching here but cannot come up with an answer so I wanted to ask if this was possible...

I want to create a conditional join based on the value of field in the database. So for example if the value is 1 then join one table if the value is 2 then join a different table.

Here is some sample data I have to work with:

```
Templates Table

template_id     name               type
     1          Email Template      1
     2          Page Template       2


Email Templates Table

template_id      email_subject      email_body
     1               test             test


Page Templates Table

template_id       page_title     page_desc
    2              test page        testing
```

So the templates table contains all the generic template information and the other tables contins information specific to the template type.

Is it possible to create a conditional mysql join so if the type in the templates table is 1 then from the email table and if the type is 2 then join from the page table?

If not could anybody suggest a better database design for the templates?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(e.email_subject, p.page_title) title_or_subject,
       coalesce(e.email_body, p.page_desc) body_or_desc
from Templates t
left join EmailTemplates e on t.type=1 and e.template_id=t.template_id
left join PageTemplates p on t.type=2 and p.template_id=t.template_id
```

The double left joins will show all templates even if it cannot be matched from either table (depending on type).  Otherwise if it must exist in the template table representing the type, then

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(e.email_subject, p.page_title) title_or_subject,
       coalesce(e.email_body, p.page_desc) body_or_desc
from Templates t
left join EmailTemplates e on t.type=1 and e.template_id=t.template_id
left join PageTemplates p on t.type=2 and p.template_id=t.template_id
where ((t.type = 1 and e.template_id is not null)
   or (t.type = 2 and p.template_id is not null))
```

Comment: You could always do a FULL OUTTER JOIN.  Although when joining 3 tables you're going to end up with a cartesian product of all three tables which may end up being huge!

Comment: Thanks for the answer i've just tested and it works well. Would you suggest I stick with this query and database design or is there a better/more efficient way to do this?