# MySQL: INNER JOIN query in an EITHER-OR situation

Tags: mysql

I need to find all `User`s that belong to a certain `Country` (`ID = 4321`). But a `User`'s `Location` can have...

- **EITHER** a `City`
- **OR** a `Cityaddition`, as you can see in...

The database schema:

```
User -< Locations >- City         >- District >- Region >- Country
                  >- Cityaddition >- District >- Region >- Country


Legend: (read from left to right)

-< : "...has many..."
>- : "...has one..."
```

How do I have to modify my query below in order to make this **EITHER**-**OR** condition work in 1 single query?

(Currently, this query only selects `User`s that have **BOTH** a `City` **AND** a `Cityaddition`, which is never the case in reality.)

```mysql
SELECT users.* FROM users

INNER JOIN locations ON locations.user_id = users.id

INNER JOIN cities    ON cities.id = locations.city_id
INNER JOIN districts ON districts.id = cities.district_id
INNER JOIN regions   ON regions.id = districts.region_id

INNER JOIN cityadditions           ON cityadditions.id = locations.cityaddition_id
INNER JOIN districts
           districts_cityadditions ON districts_cityadditions.id = cityadditions.district_id
INNER JOIN regions
           regions_districts       ON regions_districts.id = districts_cityadditions.region_id

WHERE (regions.country_id = 4321)
```

Comment: Do two separate queries, then combine them with `UNION`.

Comment: Thank you. I would have preferred to do it in 1 single query, if there is a sensible way to do it.

Comment: There's no such thing as a conditional join. You might be able to do it with left join, but that's more complicated and more expensive.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368842/how-to-join-conditionally-with-different-tables?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C122.1862 for how to do it with union, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446859/is-this-mysql-conditional-join-possible?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C77.3275 for how to do it with left join.

Comment: Two separate queries, unioned, will likely be easier to maintain and easier for the planner to optimise. Asking the planner to cater for both branches At The Same Time is a route to pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a single query, you can do based on a parallel hierarchy and doing a logical NOT NULL on either side.  Two separate via would be better as Barmar indicates due to the explicit OR.

Also, use aliases to shorten and make more readable and you can remove all those `ticks`.  You typically only need those when dealing with column names that are also reserved words.

```
SELECT 
      u.* 
   FROM 
      users u
         JOIN locations l
            ON u.id = l.user_id
            LEFT JOIN cities c
               ON l.city_id = c.id
               JOIN districts d
                  ON c.district_id = d.id
                  INNER JOIN regions r
                     ON d.region_id = r.id
                    AND r.country_id = 4321
            LEFT JOIN cityadditions ca
               ON l.cityaddition_id =  ca.id
               JOIN districts d2
                  ON ca.district_id = da.id
                  JOIN regions r2
                     ON d2.region_id = r2.id
                    AND r2.country_id = 4321
   where
         r.id IS NOT NULL
      OR r2.id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Won't this result in a full table scan?  Twice for some tables?  For a large users base this doesn't seem scalable.

Comment: @MatBailie, I agree, but only a full table scan once at the outer user since that is the driving force.  However, I also noted that Barmar's solution WOULD be better for scalability purposes.  I see your answer offers the inner UNION query joining to the rest, so I would leave that for Tom.

Answer (score 0):

Using `UNION`, but minimising code repetition, and the number of redundant joins...

- The planner is also able to use indexing to minimise query cost

```
SELECT DISTINCT -- all queries MAY need this, depending on the structure of your data
  `users`.*
FROM
  `regions`
INNER JOIN
  `districts`
    ON `districts`.`region_id` = `regions`.`id`
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    `locations`.`id`,
    `cities`.`district_id`
  FROM
    `locations`
  INNER JOIN
    `cities`
        ON `cities`.`id` = `locations`.`city_id`

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    `locations`.`id`,
    `cityadditions`.`district_id`
  FROM
    `locations`
  INNER JOIN
    `cityadditions`
        ON `cityadditions`.`id` = `locations`.`cityaddition_id`
)
  AS `locations`  
    ON `locations`.`district_id` = `district`.`id`
INNER JOIN
  `users`
    ON `users`.`location_id` = `locations`.`id`
WHERE
  `regions`.`country_id` = 4321
```